# ! Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Psr\Log\LogLevel'

Tags: symfony, package, installation

In my symfony project I can't make a composer require psr/log. I got this error message:

```
!!  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Psr\Log\LogLevel' not found in C:\wamp64\ww
w\my-project\vendor\symfony\debug\Debug.php:53
!!  Stack trace:
!!  #0 C:\wamp64\www\my-project\bin\console(32): Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug::ena
ble()
!!  #1 {main}
!!    thrown in C:\wamp64\www\my-project\vendor\symfony\debug\Debug.php on line 5
3
!!
```

Comment: Can you please show the output of `composer show` as well as the content of your `composer.json` file?

Answer (score 0):

ok so , i deleted all in vendor directory with "composer install"

Comment: Is that the solution? Or is this another feedback on a (possibly now deleted) comment? Please create one answer which actually describes and explains a solution. Then delete everything else.

Answer (score -1):

ok yes,

```
php {
"type": "project",
"license": "proprietary",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
    "symfony/asset": "4.3.*",
    "symfony/console": "4.3.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "4.3.*",
    "symfony/expression-language": "4.3.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.1",
    "symfony/form": "4.3.*",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.3.*",
    "symfony/http-client": "4.3.*",
    "symfony/intl": "4.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/orm-pack": "*",
    "symfony/process": "4.3.*",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "4.3.*",
    "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/translation": "4.3.*",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "4.3.*",
    "symfony/validator": "4.3.*",
    "symfony/web-link": "4.3.*",
    "ext-http": "*",
    "symfony/yaml": "4.3.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "symfony/debug-pack": "*",
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
    "symfony/profiler-pack": "*",
    "symfony/test-pack": "*",
    "symfony/web-server-bundle": "4.3.*"
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": {
        "*": "dist"
    },
    "sort-packages": true
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"replace": {
    "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
    "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
},
"scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
        "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
        "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
    },
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ]
},
"conflict": {
    "symfony/symfony": "*"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony": {
        "allow-contrib": false,
        "require": "4.3.*"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is  feedback on a comment, isn't it? In that case it is not appropriate as an answer and should be edited into the question instead.